# FOSRestBundle route

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I use Symfony2.2 and FOSRestBundle

I set

```
#app/config/config/yml
myapp_rest:
    resource: "@MyappRestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    type: rest
    prefix:   /v1
```

and

```
#src/Myapp/RestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
user:
    resource: Myapp\RestBundle\Controller\UserController
    type:     rest
```

my UserController extends FOSRestController and have method `cgetAction()` and `newAction()`. And when I try to router:debug, route shows:

.. symfony routes ..

```
get                       GET    ANY  /v1/{id}.{_format}
new                       GET    ANY  /v1/new.{_format}
```

what I expected, according to the docs, is something like

```
"get_users"     [GET] /users
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read the routing docs. If you want /users you have to use getUsersAction:

> public function getUsersAction()
>       {} // "get_users"     [GET] /users

Otherwise read the Implicit resource name definition section.

[FOS Rest Routing](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md)

Comment: Thanks, I miss the `implements ClassResourceInterface`. It works as expected now. I am using implicit resource name